# Matching endwith python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, paramiko

I am using paramiko for ssh and waiting for prompt that is checking endswith string.

actual endswith string is below:

```
 RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:asr1#
```

I am using in code to check endswith is

```
#
```

below is the code:

```
import paramiko
import re
import time
hostname = "10.10.10.10"
net_username = "user"
net_password = "password"
remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()
remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
     paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
remote_conn_pre.connect(hostname, username=net_username, password=net_password,look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
    print(resp)
remote_conn.send("\n")
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
    print(resp)
remote_conn.send("ping 172.16.35.22\n")
time.sleep(2)
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('#'):
    resp = remote_conn.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
    print resp
```

Everything work fine even i used "#" to check endswith but i want to double check here. Is i am doing it right way or we have some other better options to achieve this

I mean in endswith string "RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:asr1#".

```
 "RP/" is constant
```

How to use it re that match

```
 "RP/anything#"
```

Comment: `re.compile(r"(RP/[a-z]*#{1})")` and this is not the best re. But it helps you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python's [regular expression module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to enhance your search :

You have to use `re.match` to match your regular expression with your string :

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.
>
> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.
>
> If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead (see also search() vs. match()).

There is an example for your issue :

```
import re # module for regular expression

string = "RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:asr1#"
match = re.match(r"^RP/[(\d|\w)|(/|:)]*#{1}$", string)
if (match):
    # The string match with the regular expression
else:
    # The string doesn't match the regular expression
```

If you don't know how to use regular expressions and you would like to practice them , you can use this website : [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). This website has also python's module for regular expressions.